# Visual Studio 2015 - How to stop EntryPointNotFoundException when starting to debug an app?

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am running Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 7 laptop, and every time I start up an application in the IDE's debugger I am presented with the following exception:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'EventSetInformation' in DLL 'advapi32.dll'.

[image]

I have found reference to this in the [coreclr repository on github](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/974) indicating this is an API that was added in Windows 8. My case is similar to the github issue, and I can click 'Continue' to ignore the exception and my applications run just fine. However, this is really annoying because I can't just start debugging apps without waiting for this exception to get thrown so I can manually continue past it.

My question is whether anyone knows if I can prevent this exception from breaking in the IDE? This situation is just a nuisance at the moment, but one I'd love to get rid of.

*For reference, in this case changing the Exception settings within Visual Studio doesn't seem to change the behavior. Here's screenshots for both enabling and disabling CLR exceptions, along with the exception:*

*CLR Exceptions disabled*
[image: screenshot with CLR exceptions disabled]

*CLR Exceptions enabled*
[image: screenshot with CLR exceptions enabled]

**Solution**

This is caused by a general debugger option that seems to override any exception-specific setting. As indicated by @John in his answer below, there's a debugger option you disable to stop this behavior. When this option was *checked* I would get the break point described, but un-checking it stops that and provides what I was looking for:

[image: Option to remove to disable this behavior]

Comment: Just don't ask the debugger to stop when this exception is thrown.  Debug > Windows > Exceptions Settings.   Click the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox until it turns into a solid rectangle.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the suggestion, but in this case changing whether CLR exceptions should break doesn't change how VS behaves. I'll update the question with screenshots to demonstrate this.

Comment: Can you change the target framework to 4.5.2 instead of 4.6?

Comment: @Thomas The target framework for this app is in fact 4.5.2. I have other applications that target 4.5 and also exhibit this behavior. I don't expect you to explore the code, but for reference the examples above were generated from this small project - https://github.com/sstorie/SerilogDemo.Wpf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By the looks of your screenshots, I would guess you have enabled the Debugger option "Break when exceptions cross AppDomains or managed/native boundaries". Go to Debugger->Options and uncheck that option (3rd from the top)

Comment: That was it! I've updated the answer with a screenshot showing this setting visually. Thanks @John.

Comment: My apologies @John...I thought I had accepted this answer, but realized yesterday that I hadn't. Thanks for submitting it.

Answer (score 6):

A co-worker just hit this issue and he had to check the 'Enable Just My Code' box found in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General along with clearing the check on 'Break when exceptions cross AppDomains or managed/native boundaries'.

Comment: hmm I have no idea why this is thrown or what this means but it did the trick +1

Answer (score 0):

See this screenshots, I  have enabled the Debugger option "Break when s cross AppDomains or managed/native boundaries". Go to Debugger->Options and uncheck that option . Its work fine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5QZc.png)